# Power function from math module seems to stop working in Python

Tags: python

So i'm trying to write a program which finds a Pythagorean triplet, checks if all the numbers which make up the triplet add up to 1000, and if they do then multiply the 3 numbers together and output the result. Here is my sample code:

```
    import math

numbers = [1,2,3]
found = False
while not found:
    if (math.pow(numbers[0], 2) + math.pow(numbers[1], 2)) == (math.pow(numbers[2], 2)): #Checks to see if its a pythag triplet
        total = 0
        for x in numbers:#adds the 3 numbers together
            total += x
        if total == 1000: #if the total of the three numbers is 1000, multiply them all together
            product = 1
            for y in numbers:
                product *= y
            print (product)
            found = True #print the product total and end the while loop
        else: 
            numbers = [z+1 for z in numbers] #if the total isnt 100, then just add 1 to each of the three numbers
            print (numbers) 
    else:
        numbers = [z+1 for z in numbers]#if the three numbers arent pythag triplet, then add 1 to each number
```

When the first triplet has been found the program seems to stop working. It dosnt seem to be able to identify any pythag triplets anymore, so I guess this is due to the "pow" function not working correctly anymore? I am new to programming so would appreciate any advice on how to overcome this and also how I could improve efficiency aswell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, your math is incorrect.

1. On each iteration, *every* number in the triplet is increased by 1
2. After `a` iterations, in order for it to be a Pythagorean triplet, the following must hold true:

   ```
   (a + 1)**2 + (a + 2)**2 == (a + 3)**2
   ```

   Here 1, 2 and 3 inside the parentheses are the initial contents of the list `numbers`.
3. This simplifies to `2 * a**2 + 6 * a + 5 == a **2 + 6 * a + 9`
4. Which is true only for `a == 2`

So, your code executes `print (numbers)` on the *third (`a + 1`)* iteration and will never terminate since `a` is always increasing.

Comment: Isn't it rather an infinite loop?

Comment: According to OP, "When the first triplet _has been found_ the program seems to stop working". If the triplet has been found, `print (product)` is executed, and the next line is `found = True`, which terminates the loop.

Comment: There's an other `print(product)`, not just the one in `if total == 1000:` which never happens.

Comment: Ahh maybe i should have made it a bit more clear - Im looking for the first 3 pythagorean triplets which have a total of 1000, then finding the product of those 3 numbers. I cant just count the amount of numbers found then stop the while loop as I don't know how many numbers it will take to find the first triplet which satisfies the question (do I?). The "found = True" line is meant to stop the program as it is only meant to be called when we have found the 3 numbers which satisfy the original question.

Comment: @Keldorn, yep, I run the code, and it doesn't terminate, indeed

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is running an infinite loop. The condition leading to `found = True` is never met, so it just keeps running.

The condition to print something (`(math.pow(numbers[0], 2) + math.pow(numbers[1], 2)) == (math.pow(numbers[2], 2))`) just happens once, as you see printed on your screen.

You should add debug output to see what your algorithm does.

Are you sure there are integers with:

- n^2 + (n+1)^2 = (n+2)^2
- 3*n +3 = 1000

If not, the loop won't stop. The second condition can be re-written as n = 1000/3 -1. It is not an integer, so the program is never stopping. But I suspect the first equation also have a single solution, for n=3.

Comment: Youre right. Ive been looking at this all wrong. Ive assumed that the only way to form a triplet is by using 3 consecutive numbers. It never occurred to me that the 3 numbers could have a difference of more than 1.